# How to modify two inter-related lists simultaneously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two blank lists: `intitialList` and `finalList` and one initial value which is supposed to go into the `initialList` and a sample list `sampleList = [12,3,1,4,25,3,2,22,12,32,34,2,1,5,7]`. Now what I want to do is to write a program that will first insert initial values in the `initialList` then do some calculations and insert the value in `finalList` and then the first values of the `finalList` become the 2nd value of the `initialList` and again do some calculation and so on. Its kind of zigzag thing. Values are filling in zigzag way. My approach:

```
intialList = []
finalList = []
intialValue = 30
eff = 0.25
sampleList = [12,3,1,4,25,3,2,22,12,32,34,2,1,5,7]
for a in sampleList:
    if a < 10:
        intialList.append(intialValue)
        finalList.append(intialValue + intialValue*eff)
    else:
        intialList.append(intialValue)
        finalList.append(intialValue - intialValue*eff)
print("initial list:", intialList)
print("final list:", finalList)
```

I seriously don't know how to approach this. 
desired output:

```
initial list: [30, 22.5, 28.125, 35.156, 43.954, 32.96, 24.72]
finalist list: [22.5, 28.125, 35.156, 43.945, 32.96, 24.72]
```

the results are stored in the `finalList` and first the `initial value` is stored at the index 0  of `initialList` after that the final result from the `finalList` is stored in the `initialList`.

Comment: It looks like `finalList` is just `initialList[1:]`? Apart from `43.954 != 43.945` which I assume is a typo?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you've written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your desired output you want to change the `intalValue` during `sampleList` iteration:

```
finalList = []
intialValue = 30
intialList = [intialValue]

eff = 0.25
sampleList = [12,3,1,4,25,3,2,22,12,32,34,2,1,5,7]


for a in sampleList:
    if a < 10:
        calculated_value = intialValue + intialValue * eff

    else:
        calculated_value = intialValue - intialValue * eff

    intialValue = calculated_value
    finalList.append(intialValue)
    intialList.append(intialValue)

print(intialList)    
print(finalList)
```

**output:**

```
[30, 22.5, 28.125, 35.15625, 43.9453125, 32.958984375, 41.19873046875, 51.4984130859375, 38.623809814453125, 28.967857360839844, 21.725893020629883, 16.294419765472412, 20.368024706840515, 25.460030883550644, 31.825038604438305, 39.78129825554788]
[22.5, 28.125, 35.15625, 43.9453125, 32.958984375, 41.19873046875, 51.4984130859375, 38.623809814453125, 28.967857360839844, 21.725893020629883, 16.294419765472412, 20.368024706840515, 25.460030883550644, 31.825038604438305, 39.78129825554788]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
for a in sampleList:
    if a < 10:
        intialList.append(intialValue)
        finalList.append(intialValue + intialValue*eff)
        intialValue += initalValue*eff
    else:
        intialList.append(intialValue)
        finalList.append(intialValue - intialValue*eff)
        intialValue -= initalValue*eff
```